# $\int_{X} f^p d\mu = \int_{[0,\infty)} p y^{p-1} \mu(\{x \ \mid \ f(x) \geq y \}) d\mathcal{L}^1(y) $ for $p \geq 1$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> Let $p \geq 1$ and let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $f: X \to [0,\infty) $ be measurable. How do we prove that $$\int_{X} f^p d\mu = \int_{[0,\infty)} p y^{p-1} \mu(\{x \ \mid \ f(x) \geq y \}) d\mathcal{L}^1(y). $$

I know that if we let $E = \{(x,y) \in X \times \mathbb{R} \ \mid \ 0 \leq y \leq f^p(x) \}$, we then have, from Tonelli's theorem, that $$(\mu \times \mathcal{L}^1)(E) = \int_X \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{E_x}(y) d\mathcal{L}^1(x) d\mu(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} \int_X 1_{E^y}(x) d\mu(y) d\mathcal{L}^1(x), $$ where $\mathcal{L}^1 $ is the Lebesgue measure and $$E_x = \{y \in  \mathbb{R} \ \mid \ (x,y) \in E\} $$ and $$E^y = \{x \in X \ \mid \ (x,y) \in E \}. $$

Now, it's easy to see that $$\int_X \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{E_x}(y) d\mathcal{L}^1(x) d\mu(y) = \int_X f^p d\mu, $$ but I cannot see why $$\int_\mathbb{R} \int_X 1_{E^y}(x) d\mu(y) d\mathcal{L}^1(x) = \int_{[0,\infty)} p y^{p-1} \mu(\{x \ \mid \ f(x) \geq y \}) d\mathcal{L}^1(y),$$ because I get that $$\int_\mathbb{R} \int_X 1_{E^y}(x) d\mu(y) d\mathcal{L}^1(x) = \int_{[0,\infty)} \mu (\{x \in X \mid \ f^p(x) \geq y. \} )d\mathcal{L}^1(y). $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} py^{p-1}\mu(f>y) dy$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int 1_{\{f>y\}}(x)py^{p-1}d\mu(x)dy$$ $$=^{TONELLI }\int \int_{0}^{
f(x)}  py^{p-1}dyd\mu(x) =\int f^p((x))d\mu((x))$$

Note that $1_{\{f>y\}}(x)=1$ iff $f(x)>y>0$ iff $y \in (0,f(x))$ iff $1_{(0,f(x))}(y)=1$

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. However, does measurability of the function $(x,y) \mapsto 1_{f>y} (x) py^{p-1}$ follow from the measurability of my $E$?

Comment: @S.T. Since $f$ is measurable then yes